# How can I reference pivot fields from excel table?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write code that will create a pivot table from an Excel table, and I keep getting Run-time errors that accuse me of invalid pivot field names.

```
Sub pivotTracking()

Dim wsTracking As Worksheet
Dim tblTracking As ListObject
Dim pcTracking As PivotCache
Dim ptTracking As PivotTable
Dim ptDestination As Range

Set wsTracking = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Tracking")
Set tblTracking = wsTracking.ListObjects("tblTracking")

   'Create the cache from the data range
    Set pcTracking = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
        SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:=wsTracking.Range("tblTracking").Address _
        )

    'Set table destination range
    Set ptDestination = wsTracking.Range("P2")

    'Create the Pivot table
    Set ptTracking = wsTracking.PivotTables.add( _
        PivotCache:=pcTracking, _
        TableDestination:=ptDestination, _
        TableName:="Pivot2" _
        )

    ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = True
        'Debug.Print ptTracking.PivotFields(1).Name
            'Returns nothing

    'Add fields
    With ptTracking

        With .PivotFields(Date) 'Quotes here don't help :-/
             .Orientation = xlColumnField
             .Position = 1
        End With

        With .PivotFields(TechNbr)
             .Orientation = xlRowField
             .Position = 1
        End With

        With .PivotFields(status)
             .Orientation = xlRowField
             .Position = 2
        End With

        With .PivotFields(status)
             .Orientation = xlDataField
             .Position = 1
             .caption = "TechTracker"
             .Function = xlCount
        End With

End With

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False

End Sub
```

I've tried referencing the table range in many different ways, I've tried using hard references, and I've even tried declaring variables for each pivot field.  Could anyone please help me correct the following code?

Comment: I  should clarify, in case it matters:

Comment: The variables wsTracking and tblTracking are actually Public variables that are declared elsewhere in the project.  I don't think they are the problem because they work fine in this (and other) modules, and I do make sure that they are declared and set when I test this sub.

Comment: Which lines are throwing the errors? And why do you need to create the PivotTable from scratch? Can't you create it once and then just refresh it from VBA?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As a question and answer site we try to keep the chat to a minimum, so greetings and things not directly related to the question or answer are not required. We do not need information from the tags in the the title. I've edited it down to be more like the recognised SO style which should assist in getting to the solution from those experts.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 - thank you for the edit; I will be more direct in the future.

Comment: @AnalystCave.com The error comes when I add the first field    `With Pivotfield (Date)   .Orientation:= XlColumnField  .Position=1`

Comment: @AnalystCave.com  The pivot tables will ultimately be inside of worksheets that are added while the program is being executed, and the number of added worksheets/worksheet names change depending on the data.  If I can create and hide a skeleton pivot table somewhere then that would work--I will definitely look into that option

Comment: `Date` is a data type (for dates) as opposed to your other PivotFields

Comment: @AnalystCave.com Thank you for locating the problem!  It turns out excel was inserting "today's date" as my PivotField name when I used the posted code.  Can you post your comment as an answer?  I would like to select it so that other readers can consider your insight when dealing with a similar problem.

Comment: Great. Done. Posted below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date` is a data type (for dates) as opposed to your other PivotFields